# Issue with swagger2 and SpringMVC- taking lot of time to run the app

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm currently using Springfox Swagger2 to provide API UI(Swagger-UI) and document my spring mvc application with a Java config. To starts my API it was originally taken about 90 seconds, with the whole scanning process. There are around 12-15 modules and 100 controller in my project, it was a desktop application based on servlet & hibernate technology which we are now converting to SpringMVC . After I added Swagger2 Configuration and try to run the project it was not running even after **2000s** also(my app normally take **90s** to start before adding swagger2).
Below are the statement after which my build is getting hanged/Slow :

```
S2019-11-22 18:04:59,151 - 62936 - INFO  - [127.0.0.1|main|system] - ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext():271 - Root WebApplicationContext: initialization started
S2019-11-22 18:05:01,915 - 65700 - INFO  - [127.0.0.1|main|system] - PropertySourcedRequestMappingHandlerMapping.initHandlerMethods():69 - Mapped URL path [/v2/api-docs] onto method [springfox.documentation.swagger2.web.Swagger2Controller#getDocumentation(String, HttpServletRequest)]
S2019-11-22 18:05:02,275 - 66060 - INFO  - [127.0.0.1|main|system] - DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start():160 - Context refreshed
S2019-11-22 18:05:02,347 - 66132 - INFO  - [127.0.0.1|main|system] - DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start():163 - Found 1 custom documentation plugin(s)
S2019-11-22 18:05:02,411 - 66196 - INFO  - [127.0.0.1|main|system] - ApiListingReferenceScanner.scan():41 - Scanning for api listing reference
```

I currently just need the controller information without any model info. I already excluded model scanning from the startup process in order to make my API start, but it is not working?

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    Class[] clazz = {JsonUtil.class, MasterEnum.class, MasterDataController.class,
            AppExceptionHandler.class, CountryMapper.class, MasterServiceImpl.class,
            MasterService.class, EndPointConfigurationUtil.class, MasterVO.class, CountryVO.class};

    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("com.tentelemed.eaihs.web.controller"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.regex("/.*"))
                .build()
                .apiInfo(apiInfo()).ignoredParameterTypes(clazz);
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        return new ApiInfoBuilder()
                .title("TITLE")
                .description("DESCRIPTION")
                .version("VERSION")
                .termsOfServiceUrl("http://terms-of-services.url")
                .license("LICENSE")
                .licenseUrl("http://url-to-license.com")
                .build();
    }
}
```

And are there any other ways to make it run? I'm using **swagger 2.9.2**. If you want any additional information please let me know.Thanks in advance!!!!!

EDIT::After I waited for 3596s I got below error log

```
S2019-11-22 19:03:57,608 - 3601393 - WARN  - [127.0.0.1|main|system] - AbstractApplicationContext.refresh():558 - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
S2019-11-22 19:03:57,624 - 3601409 - ERROR - [127.0.0.1|main|system] - ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext():313 - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:890)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.app.serverimpl.JettyServerManager.startJetty(JettyServerManager.java:200)
    at com.app.serverimpl.ServerMain.startServer(ServerMain.java:150)
    at com.app.serverimpl.ServerMainEA.main(ServerMainEA.java:19)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2212)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4053)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:4057)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalLoadingCache.get(LocalCache.java:4986)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.CachingModelDependencyProvider.dependentModels(CachingModelDependencyProvider.java:58)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelProvider.dependencies(DefaultModelProvider.java:128)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.CachingModelProvider.dependencies(CachingModelProvider.java:68)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiModelReader.populateDependencies(ApiModelReader.java:136)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiModelReader.read(ApiModelReader.java:78)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiListingScanner.scan(ApiListingScanner.java:133)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.scanners.ApiDocumentationScanner.scan(ApiDocumentationScanner.java:71)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.scanDocumentation(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:101)
    at springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.start(DocumentationPluginsBootstrapper.java:167)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3181)
    at java.util.ArrayList.grow(ArrayList.java:265)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureExplicitCapacity(ArrayList.java:239)
    at java.util.ArrayList.ensureCapacityInternal(ArrayList.java:231)
    at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:583)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedPropertiesAndFields(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:181)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedDependencies(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:120)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.maybeFromCollectionElementType(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:220)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedPropertiesAndFields(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:181)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedDependencies(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:120)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.maybeFromRegularType(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:207)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedPropertiesAndFields(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:183)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedDependencies(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:120)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.maybeFromRegularType(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:207)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedPropertiesAndFields(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:183)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedDependencies(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:120)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.maybeFromCollectionElementType(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:220)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedPropertiesAndFields(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:181)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedDependencies(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:120)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.maybeFromCollectionElementType(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:220)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedPropertiesAndFields(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:181)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedDependencies(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:120)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.maybeFromRegularType(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:207)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedPropertiesAndFields(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:183)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedDependencies(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:120)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.maybeFromRegularType(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:207)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedPropertiesAndFields(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:183)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.resolvedDependencies(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:120)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.DefaultModelDependencyProvider.dependentModels(DefaultModelDependencyProvider.java:79)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.CachingModelDependencyProvider$1.load(CachingModelDependencyProvider.java:50)
    at springfox.documentation.schema.CachingModelDependencyProvider$1.load(CachingModelDependencyProvider.java:48)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3628)
S2019-11-22 19:03:58,371 - 3602156 - ERROR - [127.0.0.1|main|system] - JettyServerManager.startJetty():211 - Jetty failed to start !
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'documentationPluginsBootstrapper'; nested exception is com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:185)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158)
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:894)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:553)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:401)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:292)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:103)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ContextHandler.java:890)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.callContextInitialized(ServletContextHandler.java:532)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:853)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:785)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:115)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.doStart(ContextHandlerCollection.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:133)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:418)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:113)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at com.app.serverimpl.JettyServerManager.startJetty(JettyServerManager.java:200)
    at com.app.serverimpl.ServerMain.startServer(ServerMain.java:150)
    at com.app.serverimpl.ServerMainEA.main(ServerMainEA.java:19)
Caused by: com.google.common.util.concurrent.ExecutionError: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2212)
    at com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:4053)
```

Answer (score 1):

Springfox 2.9.2 has problem with multiple mannyToManny relationships. If you have in your DAO or DTO these relationships you need to simplify them with @JsonIgnore @JsonIgnoreProperties. This is because of traversal implementation. By default springfox does not traverse every DTO only once but multiple times based on number of reference in DTO.

Comment: @JsonIgnore before the method definition?

Answer (score 0):

The solution, in my case, was to disable the lazy init (I've enabled it before):

```
spring.main.lazy-initialization=false
```

I know it's strange...